# Dynamically created dags get deleted automatically from Airflow UI

Tags: airflow

I am quite new to *Apache Airflow* so I am not sure if all features of airflow.

My requirement is to create the dynamic dags for the entries which are newly added to database. The criteria for checking if anything is newly added to DB is if the `dag_id` is updated against that entry or not. If not then we need to create a new dag for it and update the `dag_id` against that entry.

New entry in database with Dag_id as Null

```
Id  :d001   ,
Dag_id :Null
```

Once main dag (which is built to create dynamic dags) runs and fetches this entry, a dag is created and `dag_id` is updated back to database.

```
Id : d001 ,
Dag_id : dagid-001
```

The challenge I am facing is once the main dags runs again for fetching newly added entries (this time we won't be retrieving d001). The dynamic dags(dagid-001) which were previously created are getting deleted from *Airflow* UI and the *Airflow* list_dags as well.

code from main dag to create dynamic dag

```
dag_id = 'hello_world_{}'.format(str(new_entry[0]))

    default_args = {'owner': 'airflow',
                    'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1)
                    }

    schedule = ## frequency 

    dag_number = new_entry

    globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id,
                                  schedule,
                                  dag_number,
                                  default_args)
```

Is this the expected behavior of dynamic dag or am I missing something while creating them?

Answer (score 0):

For Airflow, a DAG exists only it the corresponding `DAG` object is found while scanning Python files in the `dag` directory.

So, your main DAG has to generate DAGs not only for new DB entries, but also for all previous entries too.